# Need help assigning variable from form input

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get input (specifically a number/float) from a text form, and assign it to a variable which I can use to do calculations. It should be assigned to the variable when the calculate button is clicked.

I am using getElementById() which returns undefined for me.

Previous research pointed out that I need to have my script tag below my input tag.

So I moved my script from the head tag to the body tag and I am still having trouble (still getting undefined returned).

```
<form name = "myform">
Item Price <input type = "text" name = "tPrice">
<br><br>

<input type = "button" value = "Calculate" onClick = "calculate()"/>

<input type = "submit" value = "Submit"/>
<input type = "reset" value = "Clear"/>


</form>

<script>

var totalPrice = parseFloat(document.getElementById("tPrice").value);

//var totalPrice = document.getElementById("iPrice");

//var price = document.getElementById("price").value;
//document.getElementById("price").value = totalPrice;
//var shipMeth = document.getElementById("ship").checked;



function calculate()
{

//DISPLAY Results
window.alert(totalPrice);

//shipping and handling results
document.myform.sh.value = "500";
//tax
document.myform.tax.value = "500";
//total
document.myform.total.value = "500";

//window.alert(document.myform.sh.value);

window.alert("Results function successful")
return true;
}


</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input needs an ID attribute and you might want to move the getting and parsing of value into the calculate function.

```
Item Price <input type = "text" id = "tPrice">
```

and

```
function calculate()
{

var totalPrice = parseFloat(document.getElementById("tPrice").value);
//DISPLAY Results
window.alert(totalPrice);

//shipping and handling results
document.myform.sh.value = "500";
//tax
document.myform.tax.value = "500";
//total
document.myform.total.value = "500";

//window.alert(document.myform.sh.value);

window.alert("Results function successful")
return true;
}
```

The problem is the getting of the value runs on page load, when the input has no value. If you only get the value once the button is clicked you make sure that the input has had a value set before attempting to get it.

Comment: This. Also, after doing so you won't _need_ put your `script` at the end anymore (although I believe that's still considered best practise these days anyway).

Comment: Thank you very much! Both the suggestions were spot on.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `input id="tPrice"` not the `name` property. Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thank you for the speedy response! This definitely helped, however now I am getting a return value of NaN. Any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: That will be something to do with your calculations, try printing the raw value of the input to check it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
Item Price <input type = "text" name = "tPrice">
```

to

```
Item Price <input type = "text" id = "tPrice">
```

Comment: It would probably be a good idea to leave the `name="tPrice"` as well as adding `id="tPrice"`, since `name` is used server-side when the form is submitted.

Comment: Thank you for the speedy response! I am not getting NaN instead of undefined, any ideas why this might happen?

Answer (score 0):

I would move the getElementById call into the calculate method, because if it is a text input you should calculate with its value only AFTER when the user filled it up with a value. And yes, add id to the input instead of the name attribute. If you want to save the input's value immediately when the page loads then you should wait for the DOM to be ready:

```
    $(document).ready(function() { /* code here */ });
```

And be careful, because if the value is empty the parseFloat will result a NaN.

Comment: Thank you, this was a key part in solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Put the `var` inside the function like this:

```
function calculate()
{
var totalPrice = parseFloat(document.getElementById("tPrice").value);
//DISPLAY Results
window.alert(totalPrice);

//shipping and handling results
document.myform.sh.value = "500";
//tax
document.myform.tax.value = "500";
//total
document.myform.total.value = "500";

//window.alert(document.myform.sh.value);

window.alert("Results function successful")
return true;
}
```

Then add the `id="tPrice"` to the input like this:

```
<input type = "text" name = "tPrice" id="tPrice">
```

And see fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vantbrhb/8/